# how to use local locate DB for emacs helm?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I created a local db with `updatedb -l 0 -o update.db -U .`

Now when I am under the directory where the update.db is or any other directory below it, I want helm-locate to use the update.db

(as in sublime go-to-anything with a folder)

How can I do this?
(I have to go to the directory which contains the update.db file everytime)..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `locate-make-command-line`.

```
(defun jpk/locate-make-command-line (str)
  (list locate-command "-d" "/path/to/update.db" str))
(setq locate-make-command-line 'jpk/locate-make-command-line)
```